# How can I concatenate two `&str` type elements of Rust Vector and add to Zero Index

Tags: string, vector, rust, concatenation, string-literals

```
let mut item = vec!["2", "3", "5"];
```

I want to concatenate the first and second index of this vector and replace with the value of zero index.

```
item[0] = item[0] + item[1];
```

But due to the type of vector elements being `&str` and the result I'm getting after concatenation is `String`, Rust is not letting me update the value of vector.

Comment: Why not make the entries in the vector `String` instead?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to make an expression calculator in which I take a mathmatical expression like "235+3" and then split and collect in Vector to calculate but due to split 235 is added as individual element "2","3","5" with a built-in type &Str and I have to concatenate three above &Str to append again in Vector but all the concatenation of &Str gives me a String type rather than &Str and prevents me to append String type element in between &Str type Vector.

Answer (score 9):

One way to get to the result is through Compiler Driven Development.

Starting with:

```
fn main() {
   let mut item = vec!["2","3","5"];

   let first_item = &(item[0].to_owned() + item[1]);

   item[0] = item[0] + item[1];

   println!("item {:?}", item);
}
```

We have:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&str`
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
6 |    item[0] = item[0] + item[1];
  |              ------- ^ ------- &str
  |              |       |
  |              |       `+` cannot be used to concatenate two `&str` strings
  |              &str
  |
help: `to_owned()` can be used to create an owned `String` from a string reference. String concatenation appends the string on the right to the string on the left and may require reallocation. This requires ownership of the string on the left
  |
6 |    item[0] = item[0].to_owned() + item[1];
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Following the compiler suggestion:

```
item[0] = item[0].to_owned() + item[1];
```

Now we get:

```
  |
6 |    item[0] = item[0].to_owned() + item[1];
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |              |
  |              expected `&str`, found struct `std::string::String`
  |              help: consider borrowing here: `&(item[0].to_owned() + item[1])`
```

Then applying again the suggestion:

```
  |
6 |    item[0] = &(item[0].to_owned() + item[1]);
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |               |
  |               creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
7 | 
8 |    println!("item {:?}", item);
  |                          ---- borrow later used here
```

Now the problem is related to lifetime scopes, following the compiler suggestion this is the final version:

```
fn main() {
   let mut item = vec!["2","3","5"];

   let first_item = &(item[0].to_owned() + item[1]);

   item[0] = first_item;

   println!("item {:?}", item);
}
```

The compiler has driven to a solution, but in every case you have to carefully consider if this is a solution that meets the requirements of your application.
In this case you must pay attention to lifetime scopes.

Another, more idiomatic solution, as already suggested, could be to use a Vec of String:

```
let mut item: Vec<String> = vec!["2".to_owned(), "3".to_owned(), "5".to_owned()];

item[0] = format!("{}{}", item[0], item[1]);
```

Comment: The final version is also throwing an error of lifetime scope and the other solution of manully creation of String type Vector which is not possible in my case as I am taking a String input and splitting that string to a vector dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do it in runtime, it is not possible. `&str` is non-owning type, one can't concatenate two `&str`'s into one for the storage they point to may be non-contigious.

You may achieve the goal using `String`:

```rust
let mut item = vec![String::from("2"), String::from("3"), String::from("5")];
// Vec is not empty and contains more than 1 element, it is safe to unwrap
let (first, rest) = item.split_first_mut().unwrap();
// Append the second element to the end of the first element 
first.push_str(rest[0].as_str()); 
println!("{}", &first); // 23
```